# how can i share mobile screen using agora video call in React-Native

Tags: react-native, agora.io, screensharing

how to implement screen share in agora video call in react native?
in agora documentation provide code but that not an react code  [example link](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/screensharing_android?platform=React%20Native). so how inegrated in react native.
please provide example

Answer (score 1):

The React Native SDK now supports screen-sharing. You can use the [startScreenCapture](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/react_native/classes/rtcengine.html#startscreencapture) method to share you screen.

Old Answer:
Agora React Native SDK does not support screen sharing out of the box, however you can setup screen sharing by using the underlying Android and iOS SDKs. You can use the Android example that you referenced in your example link and write a bridge to invoke the java method from React-Native.

Comment: can you provide example how and which method should i connect?

Comment: you can find the entire java implementation in your link, for react native bridge check this https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android